# How to display multiple graphs of the same size on the same page?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display 3 graphs of similar data with similar units on the same page.  However, all my graphs are being displayed as different sizes, and some parts of the graph are being cut off (i.e.: x-axis on one graph, top of bars on another graph, etc.).  I would like the size to be consistent between the three of them and all the data to be shown.

Here is what my output looks like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
# Water Behaviors Sums Table #

WaterBehavCount <- data.frame(Behavior=c("Limit household water use", "Engage in group activities to protect water quality", "Choose fewer polluting products", "Install     water efficient taps or aerators", "Install low flow shower heads", "Install a front loader washing machine", "Install a water efficient dishwasher", "Installed a rainwater tank"), Participants=c(1142, 271, 905, 817, 938, 744, 684, 481)) 

# Plot of sums for Water Behaviors # 

WaterBehavBar <- ggplot(WaterBehavCount, aes(x=reorder(Behavior, -     Participants),y=Participants)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="gray") +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  labs(x = "Water Behaviors", y = "Number of Participants", ylim = c(0, .8)) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                  axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5),
                  axis.title=element_text(size=10), legend.position="none")
WaterBehavBar

# Energy Behaviors Sums Table # 

EnergyBehavCount <- data.frame(Behavior=c("Turn the lights off when leaving a room", "Limit the use of heaters/air conditioners", "Wash clothes using cold water instead of warm/hot water", "Switch off standby mode of appliances or electronic devices ", 
                                    "Air dry laundry instead of using a clothes dryer", "Use low emission forms of transport (bus, bike, etc.)", "Engage in activities to promote renewable energy", "Install energy efficient appliances", 
                                    "Install low-energy light bulbs", " Install thermal insulation for walls or roofs", "Install solar panels for electricity and/or hot water", "Install batteries to store solar energy "),
                         Participants=c(1462, 1236, 1226, 909, 1310, 575, 498, 1040, 1230, 834, 523, 147)) 

# Plot of sums for Energy Behaviors # 

EnergyBehavBar <- ggplot(EnergyBehavCount, aes(x=reorder(Behavior, -Participants),y=Participants, fill=Behavior)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="gray") +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  labs(x = "Energy Behaviors", y = "Number of Participants", ylim = c(0, .8)) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5),
                     axis.title=element_text(size=10), legend.position="none")

EnergyBehavBar

# Biodiversity Behaviors Sums Table #

BioBehavCount <- data.frame(Behavior=c("Plant a native plant in the garden", "Provide water sources to native wildlife", "Put up a nest box for wildlife", "Engage in organized tree planting", 
                                          "Participate in wildlife monitoring programs", "Sign a petition to protect native wildlife ", "Engage in native vegetation restoration projects"),
                            Participants=c(1110, 1063, 497, 499, 351, 612, 437)) 

# Plot of sums for Biodiversity behaviors #

BioBehavBar <- ggplot(BioBehavCount, aes(x=reorder(Behavior, -Participants), y=Participants, fill=Behavior)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="gray") +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  labs(x = "Biodiversity Behaviors", y = "Number of Participants", ylim = c(0, .8)) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5),
                     axis.title=element_text(size=10), legend.position="none")
    BioBehavBar

# Combine all behavior graphs on one page

    ggarrange(WaterBehavBar,EnergyBehavBar, BioBehavBar + rremove("x.text"), 
          labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `patchwork` would be a more intuitive way of arranging plots whilst aligning axis heights. This allows a setting of display variables for all plots simultaneously. Long axis labels are tricky to work with, have attempted wrapping and resizing here (which might display better on your screen):

```r
library(patchwork)

WaterBehavBar + EnergyBehavBar + BioBehavBar +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "a", tag_suffix = ")") +
  plot_layout(ncol = 2) &
  scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_wrap(25)) &
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6, lineheight = 0.7))
```

[image]